# Cluster in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cluster-computing, cpu

I have tried the below piece of code in ubuntu

```
var cluster = exports.cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {

  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died. Trying to respawn...');
    cluster.fork();
  });

} else {

//spawn express etc

}
```

How can I check the CPU performance in ubuntu with or without using cluster in nodejs.
Any help on this will be really helpful

Comment: Run it with or without cluster and measure the performance with htop.

Comment: @freakish Any other tool which can give me a graphic representation.

Comment: I think that every ubuntu distribution comes with something called "system monitor". It should do it. You can run it from a terminal with `gnome-system-monitor`.

Comment: @freakish Using gnome-system-monitor throws some error "(gnome-system-monitor:15831): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"

Comment: Are you doing this on the server side? This is a dev tool, you need a monitor for it. Normally you can't run graphical programs on the server side (if it doesn't have a monitor). You would need some web service for that.

Comment: @freakish What web service I can use to monitor my cpu performance?